# Datepicker jQuery UI + приведение к DateTime

Tags: jquery, mvc

Добрый вечер. Подскажите как принято приводить дату формата dd-mm-yy к стандартному DateTime, выставляя время серединой дня. Сейчас в модель у меня забрасывается неверный формат, состоящий только из даты, полученной пикером, и DateTime встает в {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}. Ситуация даже интереснее. Вот вьюшка, где пикер отрабатывает нормально:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddTask", "Task", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "content"
}))
{
            <input id="datepicker" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо выбрать дату окончания задания" data-val-date="введите корректную дату">          
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="endDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Добавить</button>
}
```

Это частичное представление, так что в родителе вот:

```
$('body').on('click', '#datepicker', function (event) {
            $(this).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                minDate: +1,
                maxDate: '+2Y',

            });
            $(this).focus().get(0);

    });
```

Экшен:

```
[HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult AddTask(AddTaskModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Add();
            return PartialView("Success");
        }
        return View(new AddTaskModel());
    }
```

А вот тут уже возвращает дефолт. View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Task", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "content"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <h3>Дата окончания задания: @Model.EndTime.ToShortDateString()</h3>
    <input id="datepicker" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Необходимо выбрать дату окончания задания" data-val-date="введите корректную дату">                
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="endDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Изменить</button>
}
Я так понимаю проблема в том, что я сначала использовал свойство модели для показа и тут же меняю его дейтпикером?
```

Comment: @mikemilansky о каком языке идет речь?

Comment: C# Причем у меня 2 вьюшки - на создание объекта, там дата нормально цепляется, и вот на редактирование, где я меняю только дату в модели, но она выставляется дефолтом.

Comment: @mikemilansky покажите код, гадать на кофейной гуще не хотелось бы. А именно разметку с датапикером, кодотправки данных с клиента на сервер (формой или аяксом) и экшн на сервере, который обрабатывает получаемые данные

Comment: Помоему стандартный "глюк", скорее всего ожидается mm-dd-yy (US date format)

Comment: Написал проблему целиком. Второй экшн такой же по сути. Shurik - я тоже ожидал, что стандартный, поэтому перегрузить пробовал парсер. Тут где то глупая ошибка и моя безграмотность )))

Comment: @mikemilansky покажите пожалуйста еще и модель, которую привязываете. Проблема наверняка в ней

Comment: Ничего хитрого. Пробовал указывать тип DateTime.Date. Не помогло.
[Required]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        #region Business methods        
        public void Update()
        {
            DAL.Task.Update(Text, EndTime);
        }
        #endregion Business methods

Comment: @mikemilansky я попробовал сейчас воспроизвести вашу проблему, и у меня это не получилось - привязка в моем случае работает корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Как можно быть таким невнимательным. DreamChild, спасибо за старания! Просто вы куда внимательнее меня и имена просекли сразу в модели и в инпуте. Вся соль в name="endDate" и в модели EndTime. Просто не работало связывание. Из-за такой мелочи я перелопатил кучу вещей и заморочил людей, мда...